# incorrect table rendering in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

A table's formatting is broken when the page is refreshed, but works fine when it's resized.

I have tried to run the same piece of code in Chrome, IE and Edge, without any issues of this sort.

The SASS that handles the table formatting is the following snippet:

```css
.cv-table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 $line-spacing;
}

.cv-section-cell {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

  border-right: thin solid #000;
  padding: $line-spacing / 2;

  margin: 0;

  span {
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

The table itself looks as such:

```html
<table class="cv-table">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="cv-section-cell">
      <span>
        Experience
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="cv-section-cell">
      <span>
        2016/2017
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="cv-content-cell">
      Some other text.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cv-section-cell">
      <span>
        2017/2018
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="cv-content-cell">
      Some text.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how the page looks before reloading:

[image]

And this is how it looks after:

[image]

Comment: `$line-spacing :` variable value is ?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. The value is `20px`.

Comment: there is an issue of `.cv-table {
  border-spacing: 0 $line-spacing;
}` at first time  onload page inspect it remove it and then add it again it works in fire fox

Comment: Right, it works once I change a CSS element, but I ideally want it to work from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give some width and height to `td`

add this css to your class may it works for you

```
 .cv-section-cell {
          width: 1.5em;
          height: 1.5em;
       }
```

open this fiddle in firefox https://jsfiddle.net/fwz7k20q/4/

Comment: Well that works, but it is hard coded and if I change the padding/border spacing, it breaks...

Comment: you are using sass right? use variables and handel it technicaly

Comment: If there isn't a better answer, I will accept it since it would indeed work after testing.

Comment: there is no issue by changing padding/spacing i also changing the value of these

Comment: as you wish @TomášSláma